# mySQL multi-join with distinct count

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query 3 tables:

`classroom`:

```
id |    name  
----------------
 1 | bob's class
```

`student_enrollment`:

```
studentId | classroomId  
-----------------------
     1    |     1
```

`student_progress`:

```
studentId | dateTime 
---------------------   
    1     | 2014-08-15 09:33:23
```

and I am trying to end up with a result such as:

```
classroomName | studentId | days
------------------------------------------
Bob's class   |     1     |   112
```

Where `days` is the distinct number of days the particular student had a  `dateTime` entry.

```
SELECT classroom.name, student_enrollment.studentId, student_progress.dateTime   
FROM classroom 
JOIN student_enrollment ON student_enrollment.classroomId = classroom.id     
JOIN student_progress ON student_progress.studentId = student_enrollment.studentId 
WHERE `dateTime` >= '2014-08-01 09:00:34' 
ORDER BY classroom.name
```

Gives me a table with every `dateTime` entry for each student. Any way I've tried to add a count to the query gives me at best a result with just one student and the total count of distinct `dateTime` days.

```
SELECT classroom.name, student_enrollment.studentId, COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(student_progress.dateTime),MONTH(student_progress.dateTime),DAY(student_progress.dateTime)) AS days 
FROM classroom 
    JOIN student_enrollment ON student_enrollment.classroomId = classroom.id 
    JOIN student_progress ON student_progress.studentId = student_enrollment.studentId 
WHERE  `dateTime` >= '2014-08-01 09:00:34' 
ORDER BY classroom.name
```

I've tried moving the count to a sub-query in the join portion, and a variety of other things, but just end up with errors such as `unknown table student_progress` and just can't seem to land on the right way to put the query together to get the distinct count of `dateTime` entries for each `studentId`.

Comment: Is the complication that you want to consider *days* and not just unique `dateTime` values?

Comment: The complication was that I was just getting back a result with 1 student in 1 classroom with 'days' as a count of ALL distinct dateTime days, rather than the distinct count of days for each particular student. I guess because I had student_enrollment.studentId rather than student_progress.studentId in the SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something along these lines:

```
SELECT
    classroom.name,
    student_progress.studentId,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(student_progress.dateTime, '%y-%m-%d')) AS days
FROM classroom
JOIN student_enrollment ON
    student_enrollment.classroomId = classroom.id
JOIN student_progress ON
    student_progress.studentId = student_enrollment.studentId
GROUP BY
    classroom.name,
    student_progress.studentId;
```

This should correctly count distinct days vs. distinct values of `dateTime`.  I wouldn't suggest naming your column `dateTime` btw, bound to lead to confusion later (for you or the next dev).

Comment: Except it's not filtering dates prior to 08/01/2014. I added in WHERE `dateTime` >= '2014-08-01 09:00:34' and it still returns students,classrooms,and counts of entries from before that date. I imagine I need to put that logic in the COUNT somehow, rather than before the GROUP BY

Comment: Nevermind, what looks like dates not filtering is just a quirk of students showing up more than once in the student_enrollment table and it showing their days count for this year both in their current class and previous year's class. I should be able to figure out how to solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want is to count the distinct DATEs. Try, instead:

```
SELECT classroom.NAME,
    student_enrollment.studentId,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(student_progress.DATETIME)) AS days
FROM classroom
INNER JOIN student_enrollment
    ON student_enrollment.classroomId = classroom.id
INNER JOIN student_progress
    ON student_progress.studentId = student_enrollment.studentId
WHERE `dateTime` >= '2014-08-01 09:00:34'
GROUP BY classroom.NAME, student_enrollment.studentId,
ORDER BY classroom.NAME
```

I added in the explicit GROUP BY here too, just because anytime you are aggregating with a formula up top, you should GROUP BY the other fields. MySQL will do it anyway, but it's best to be explicit so you don't get strange results.

Comment: Ah, very close to what I posted.  This won't consider days only though will it?

Comment: Thanks for answering, and for the tips on grouping.